# Loop and print counter in arm asembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm learning arm assembly on the rpi right now.

I want to loop a certain number of times and print a program counter.

Here's my code

```
.data
ms1: .asciz "Hello.\n"
ms2: .asciz "Loading....\n"
ms3: .asciz "%d\n"
.text
.global main
.extern printf
main:
    push {ip, lr}
    ldr r0, =ms1
    bl printf
    ldr r0, =ms2
    bl printf
    mov r1, #0
    mov r5, #13
    b loop
    pop {ip, pc}
loop:
    push {r1}
    ldr r0, =ms3
    bl printf
    pop {r1}
    add r1, #1
    cmp r1, r5
    bne loop
```

Instead of printing

```
Hello
Loading....
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
12
```

, it prints an **infinite amount of ones**.

Comment: According to standard calling convention, `printf` is allowed to change `r1`. Use a callee-saved register or push-pop `r1` around the `bl printf`. Same goes for `r3`.

Comment: right above ```printf``` i added ```push {r1}``` and after it i added ```pop {r1}``` i also changed r3 to r5, but now it starts counting at 12 million or so

Comment: @Jester are you still here? I still haven't advanced....

Comment: Use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57963594/edit) and update your question with the current code.

Comment: @Jester OK did!

Comment: Looks about right, except the `pop {ip, pc}` should of course be the last line after `bne loop`. In its current place it's never reached. The `b loop` can then be deleted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199540/discussion-between-jake-and-jester).